# Why are security properties non-compositional?

Tags: software

I had a lecture in security and it was stated that security properties are non-compositional. I don't quite understand what that means and can't find anything in the internet about that.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: What's the context for the statement?

Comment: I'm seeing quite a bit about the search term "security properties are non-compositional", like: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/danupam/dfgjk-sp2011.pdf

Answer (score 6):

### Secure+secure != secure

What "non-compositional" means by definition is that if you have two components/thingies/processes/whatever that each on their own are secure (i.e. satisfy some security property) then, in general, you can *not* assume that the combination of these two will satisfy that security property; having both these together can make them both insecure.

This general principle applies to many domains of security from app development to theoretical cryptography; many practical exploitable vulnerabilities occur from an unexpected interaction of two parts that each, when viewed in isolation, would be perfectly secure.